# EDMX new column generates error on ToList() call

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, edmx

We've added a new column to a database table. The column is defined as follows:

```
Name: DisplayAsSoldOut
Type: Boolean
NOT NULLABLE
Default Value: 0
```

We've refreshed our EDMX data model and the new column appears just fine. We are on an ASP.NET 4.0 platform using C#.

We have a class defined as PagedList which inherits from List and implenents an interface IPagedList

Within the PagedList we have the following method:

```
protected void Initialize(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize, int? totalCount)
{
    if (index < 0)
    { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageIndex cannot be below 0."); }

    if (pageSize < 1)
    { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageSize cannot be less than 1."); }

    if (source == null)
    { source = new List<T>().AsQueryable(); }

    if (!totalCount.HasValue)
    { TotalItemCount = source.Count(); }

    PageSize = pageSize;
    PageIndex = index;

    if (TotalItemCount > 0)
    { PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalItemCount / (double)PageSize); }
    else
    { PageCount = 0; }

    HasPreviousPage = (PageIndex > 0);
    HasNextPage = (PageIndex < (PageCount - 1));
    IsFirstPage = (PageIndex <= 0);
    IsLastPage = (PageIndex >= (PageCount - 1));

    if (TotalItemCount > 0)
    { AddRange(source.Skip((index) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()); }
}
```

When we reach the following line:

```
{ AddRange(source.Skip((index) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()); }
```

we receive the following Exception ...

```
Type: System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException
Inner Exception: "Invalid column name 'DisplayAsSoldOut'."
```

I've tried searching for this type of exception but to no avail. The column appears in the EDMX dataset just fine. I even created a small throwaway program and imported the EDMX to do a simple read from the database and it worked fine. Has anyone run across something similar?

I apologize for the lengthy post but wanted to present as much info as I could.

Comment: Have you tried removing the table and re-adding it to the EDMX?

Comment: @Theun yep ... didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post your AddRange method's source code?

Comment: @Andrei the AddRange function is just the base AddRange method off of the List<T> data type..

Comment: Well then... I had a similar problem before. You can I did 2 things to troubleshoot(they are not related to each other, but can help you to move in the right direction).
3. Try to rename the column, just for the sake of it. |
Hope this will help you.
1. Create a new EF model from scratch only with the tables you need. Run your code against the model. See what happens.
2. Remove the table from your existing model. Save. Close the VS. Start the VS. Open the model. Add the table again. Save. Build. (this helped me).

Comment: 3. Try to rename the column, just for the sake of it. | Hope some of these will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem that was related to the edmx file being wrong needed fixing manually.

These files are a little hard to edit, so to figure out what was wrong I made a backup deleted and re-added the entire Model.edmx and Model.designer.cs

Then using good old winmerge I compared the two sets of files and figured out what was wrong. It was so esoteric I can't actually remember the details, but I think it was an extra or a missing entry from one of the EDMX sections.